# $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\int_0^{2k\pi}\sqrt{\sin^{2n}(x)+\cos^{2n}(x)}dx$

Tags: integration, limits, trigonometry, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I think the limit value of the function $\sin^{2n}(x) + \cos^{2n}(x)$ when $n$ tends to infinity is $0$ for all real values of $x$ except when $x$ is an integral multiple of $\pi$, where it comes out to be one.

Is my thinking correct?

(Keep in mind that I am a high school student, so please bear with me if I've used incorrect mathematical terminologies anywhere, I'm apologizing in advance... Also, kindly try to explain as lucidly as possible.)
If this question is way above my level, then let me know that too in the comments.

If my approach is correct, then that would mean the function is discrete (I'm not sure if its the right term to use here), so how would we find the integral of it?
If not, please guide me to the right approach to solve this question.

Comment: Is the $k$ in the upper limit of integration supposed to be $n$?

Comment: Right, as $n$ increases, the integrand goes to zero except at $x$ a multiple of $\pi/2,$ where the integrand is $1.$

Comment: @peterag Your font isnt legible in my device...

Comment: @peterag Do you mean 2kπ?

Comment: @SpaceSkiier I'm using 'standard' TeX formatting, so it's bizarre if my comment is illegible on your device, but somebody else's (for instance that of mjw above) is legible. Hmn. But yes, I was wondering whether your k in the upper limit (multiplied by two pi) was a typo, and you meant it to be an n. Given your reply, apparently not!

Comment: @peterag Actually, all of the TeX formatting is illegible to me, including that of mgw, I now suppose it is due to the fact that I was using the app version of SE. I just found out that it has been discontinued from use on Android (i.e. removed from Play Store) just a while back, but I still have it on my device, so its somehow working for me.

Comment: Your idea is correct. To see how we treat the "discrete" points, have a look at measure theory and especially [Lebesgue integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration). To see how to change the orders of the limit and the integral, have a look at [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

Comment: Without measure theory, use the fact that the integrand is $\pi/2$-periodic and is $\leqslant 1$ if $n>0$. So you just have to show the claim for $\int_0^{\pi/2}$. Pick any "small" $\epsilon>0$, write $\int_0^{\pi/2}=\int_0^{\epsilon/2}+\int_{\epsilon/2}^{(\pi-\epsilon)/2}+\int_{(\pi-\epsilon)/2}^{\pi/2}$, see that the middle integral tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, and the sum of the other two is $\leqslant\epsilon$. As $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, you get 0 as the answer.

Comment: (BTW, the integrand is $1$ when $x$ is an integral multiple of $\color{red}{\pi/2}$, not just $\pi$.)

Comment: @metamorphy Thanks for the help!